# Delete a character from the last line of a bash array

Tags: bash, array

I would like to do the same thing as this topic but with bash in version **4.1.2**.

I can get the chain I want with the following command:

```
echo ${arr[@]:(-1)} | sed "s/,$///"
```

However, I would like to modify the value of the index in the array and not only display it.

**EDIT**

I specify that when I want to perform this character deletion, I am in a loop and I have reached the last element. I would therefore like to modify the penultimate element of my array.

Currently I get the following result:

```
"array" : {
  "key1" : "value1",
  "key2" : "value2",
  "key3" : "value3",
  "key4" : "value4",
  "key5" : "value5",
}
```

I would like to remove the last comma **(,)** from the key5 index.

(At this moment I am at the next line at the level of **}**)

**EDIT2**

My loop

```
while read line
do
    if [[ $line == *"<templateIdentifier>"* ]];then
        if [[ $FILENUMBER == $NUMBEROFFILES ]];then
            continue
        elif [[ $FILENUMBER < $NUMBEROFFILES ]];then
            nameArray=$(echo "customData")
            arr[$INDEXARR]='"'$nameArray'" : {'
            ((INDEXARR++))
            continue
        fi
    elif [[ $line == *"</templateIdentifier>"* ]];then
        if [[ $FILENUMBER < $NUMBEROFFILES ]];then
            continue
        elif [[ $FILENUMBER == $NUMBEROFFILES ]];then
            echo ${arr[@]:(-1)} | sed "s/,$//"
            arr[$INDEXARR]=' }'
            continue
        fi
    elif [[ $line == *['<']* ]] && [[ $line != *[?'!'-]* ]] && [[ $line != *"<templateIdentifier>"* ]];then
            name=$(echo $line | awk -F '<' {'print $2'} | awk -F '>' {'print $1'})
            value=$(echo $line | awk -F '>' {'print $2'} | awk -F '</' {'print $1'})
            arr[$INDEXARR]=$(echo -e ' \t ')'"'$name'" : "'$value'",'
            ((INDEXARR++))
    else
        continue
    fi
done < $file
```

Comment: You mean from the last element of the array?

Comment: I specify that when I want to perform this character deletion, I am in a loop and I have reached the last element. I would therefore like to modify the penultimate element of my array.

Comment: I'm confused, are you talking about bash arrays or json dicts? Please provide the loop your talking about ... and if applicable the input.

Comment: not an answer to the question, but you should definitely use an XML parser for that.